# Android - how to change Recyclerview height dynamically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm stuck with an issue about changing Recycler height based on its total items. 
What I have tried is to use Layout Param like this:

```
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = itemHeight * numberOfItem;
        myRecyclerView.requestLayout();
```

or

```
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new  RecyclerView.LayoutParams(..WRAP_CONTENT, ...WRAP_CONTENT);;
       params.height = itemHeight * numberOfItem;
       myRecyclerView..setLayoutParams(params);
```

But it didn't work. 
How can I do it ? Please help me !

Comment: yep, i forgot to notice that. 

The reason is i want to use multi recyclerview at time inside a scroolview. 

And, if i set the height of any recyclerview to wrapcontent it will take all the whole space, but it work when i set a fixed height like 100dp for ex.

So, i i'm finding the way to change the height of recyclerview dinamically.

Comment: in fact, my app have a form that allow user input data and he can add new form much as much he want by hit an "+" button. So, i'm trying the way that when he hit the "+" button i going to add one item to recyclerview, so i can control everything via recyclerview. At this time, to save time, i choose another way to do it but still want to know how can do it by this way. And maybe there are alot of people want to know too.

Comment: https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/adjust-recyclerview-item-height-example/

Comment: I was stuck with the same, and then realised that the height is set in pixels. To set in dp, we need to convert the height into dp - `(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, heightInPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        `

Answer (score 14):

You should use LayoutParams of parent's view in setLayoutParams(params).

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
 </Relativelayout>
```

Change LayoutParams in the code.

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
 recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I just changed Linearlayout to Relative then it automatically resided.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this. It worked. May be help.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {

    //this change height of rcv
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     params.height =80; //height recycleviewer
     feedListRowHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);

    feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
    feedListRowHolder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.get(i, false));

    feedListRowHolder.setClickListener(new FeedListRowHolder.ClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v, int pos, boolean isLongClick) {
            if (isLongClick) {

                // View v at position pos is long-clicked.
                String poslx = pos + "";
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "longclick " + poslx, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                // View v at position pos is clicked.
                String possx = pos + "";
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "shortclick " + possx, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                toggleSelection(pos);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: take a look on your code, it seem you was trying to change the height of each item inside recycler view. But i want to change the height of recyclerview instead.

Comment: You write params.height = itemHeight * numberOfItem; When you know number of items you can set height of recycleviewer. But you probably want fixed height of item a set height of recycleviewer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want your recycler view to size automatically as per number of items then, why don't you put RecyclerView height as wrap_content.

If you have multiple ScrollView in layout then try wrapping RecyclerView in NestScrollView and set it's height as wrap_content too.

code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the question was asked quite some time ago, I figured some might find this answer helpful.

I have a RecyclerView with adapter. The height is set in `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter:

Layout:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/container"
  ...
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public abstract static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
    public abstract void setFixedHeight();
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view) {

        @Override
        public void setFixedHeight() {
            //  magic happening here
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams parentParams = parent.getLayoutParams();
            parentParams.height =
                ((RecyclerView) parent).computeVerticalScrollRange()
                    + parent.getPaddingTop()
                    + parent.getPaddingBottom();
            parent.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
        }
    }; 
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setFixedHeight();
    }

// other methods here
}
```

Setting adapter:

`recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(...));`

**Note:** Use`((RecyclerView) parent).computeHorizontalScrollRange()` with horizontal scroll

Answer (score -2):

This code works I am sure about it

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recyclerview.getLayoutParams();
params.height=100;
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The other thing you could do is make a linear layout as the parent of the recycler view and then increase the height dynamically for the parent view

Consider the following XML below

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/yourLayoutId">

    <RecyclerView android:width="match_parent" android:height="wrap_content">
    </RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout
```

Consider the following code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 100;
```