# RecyclerView Height Expand and Collaps?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, expand

Initially I set Fixed Height of `Recyclerview` in xml. Then I am Trying to Expand  `Recyclerview` Height and Collaps it cannot be modified properly. Anyone Send the any libraries which is suited for me or How to resolved it.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what exactly you are asking in your post. Would you mind going into more detail as clearly as you can so I could better assist you? If I am understanding this correctly it sounds like you declared a `dp` value on the height of your recycler. You may want to switch the height to `wrap_content`

Comment: so, you want to make it bigger after expanding or what?

Comment: expanding the Recyclerview Height via programmatically and also collapse to Original Height

Comment: Do you want the height of each RecyclerView Item to expand and collapse depending on the item's data?

Comment: no i want expand only Recyclerview Height for showing more Items in a Layout.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405919/android-how-to-change-recyclerview-height-dynamically).

Comment: it Setted Height programmatically fine but not smoothly. also i want to show original height after i am expanding it. please help this.

Comment: RecyclerView height automatically increases depending on the number of Items passed to it.. Just set the Height of RecyclerView to wrap_content. Add some 10 items and check if it is increasing. Collapsing also is handled depending on the number items.

Comment: ok i will check tomorrow and thanks for this clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need this [expandable-recycler-view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) or [Expandable Recycle View](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview)

Comment: No sir. this is not i needed. i am already set fixed height for Recyclerview  in xml  . its ok but user wants expand to show more items. This is my problem. how to expand it

Comment: this is not suited for me.

Comment: i want expand only Recyclerview Height for showing more Items  and  i want to show original height after i am expanding it.

Comment: Are you using RecycleView inside ScrollView ..?

Comment: then you should done like this.. https://todayandroid04.blogspot.com/2017/10/listview-into-scrollview.html

Comment: set Height programmatically its done better and finished my task. thanks to all

Comment: Okay.. Just Accept the answer for other